# Tensorflow - Visualizing MNIST convolutional neural network, kernels never change

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I wanted to to show how the kernels change while training a simple 2 convolution layer similar to the one from google. https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros

I'm having this issue though where the kernels aren't actually changing. I grab the weights/kernels tensor from the first convolution layer when I built it, and after 1 image is trained I display the kernels. Then I let it train longer, where testing accuracy gets in the 90s, and display the kernels again. The problem is they are exactly the same. I was expecting to see smooth edges, but everything looks noisy like the original kernels.

The code can be found here and at the end it shows the kernels. https://github.com/sdeck51/CNNTutorials/blob/master/4.%20MNIST_Tutorial/MNISTClassification.ipynb

Any thoughts to what is wrong?

Thanks.